# Clean node template doesn't produce blocks due to "No route to host" error

Tags: substrate-node-template, error, block-production

Substrate node template (version polkadot-v0.9.26) could not find any peers including itself (as I understood) and does not produce any blocks. I did not add any lines of code.
Logs:

```
2022-08-06 16:42:58 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2022-08-06 16:42:58 creating instance on iface 10.242.1.103    
2022-08-06 16:42:58 creating instance on iface 172.23.174.132    
2022-08-06 16:42:58 creating instance on iface 10.116.116.117    
2022-08-06 16:42:58 error sending packet on iface 172.23.174.132: No route to host (os error 65)    
2022-08-06 16:43:03  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xf574…42d7), finalized #0 (0xf574…42d7), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-08-06 16:43:08  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xf574…42d7), finalized #0 (0xf574…42d7), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

What could cause such problem? I tried to run it several days ago and it worked properly, but I don't know how to trace what has changed.

I'm using macos 12.5 (intel version), firewall is off. I also have installed zerotier with several networks connected, but it wasn't a problem earlier.

Comment: what are the ips of the other peers. you seem like having an ip issue on one of your interfaces

Comment: I don't have any other peers

Comment: What's your boot command?

Comment: Just ./node-template. I forgot about --dev flag, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  its misleading, the solution is a simple mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding --dev flag to the boot command helped. Turned out this problem has no relation to network error.